# Turn python list item into dictionary key-value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I’m trying to turn the following list:

```
['06/07/20\n 22,43€ gas\n 34,70€ street toll, ' 08/07/20\n 74,90€ street toll, ' 13/07/20\n 78€ street toll\n 157,90€ gas']
```

into a dictionary like this:

```
{'06/07/20':['22,43€ gas', '34,70€ street toll'],'08/07/20':['74,90€ street toll'],'13/07/20':['78€ street toll', '157,90€ gas']}
```

What I did was:

```
for i in parsf2:
    if "/" in i:
        new_dict[i]=i
    elif "/" not in i:
         new_dict[i]=i
    else:
        x.append(i)
print(new_dict)
```

And my current result is:

```
{'06/07/20\n': '06/07/20\n', '22,43€ gas\n': '22,43€ gas\n', '34,70€ street toll\n': '34,70€ street toll\n', '\n': '\n', '08/07/20\n': '08/07/20\n', '74,90€ street toll\n': '74,90€ street toll\n', '13/07/20\n': '13/07/20\n', '78€ street toll\n': '78€ street toll\n', '157,90€ gas': '157,90€ gas'}
```

How could I easily fix my beginner's code?

Comment: what are `x` and `parsf2` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    "06/07/20\n 22,43€ gas\n 34,70€ street toll",
    " 08/07/20\n 74,90€ street toll",
    " 13/07/20\n 78€ street toll\n 157,90€ gas",
]

out = {}
for v in lst:
    s = v.split(maxsplit=1)
    if len(s) == 2: 
        k, v = s
        out[k] = [w.strip() for w in v.splitlines()]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "06/07/20": ["22,43€ gas", "34,70€ street toll"],
    "08/07/20": ["74,90€ street toll"],
    "13/07/20": ["78€ street toll", "157,90€ gas"],
}
```

---

EDIT: Short explanation:

I iterate over each value of `lst` and split it to date (first part) and the rest (using `str.split` with `maxsplit=1` parameter)

Then I split the rest over lines (`\n`) and strip whitespaces, storing the result in `out` dictionary.

Comment: would you like to explain your code plz ?

Comment: @Aymen I've added short explanation.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks! But can I do this automatically?

Comment: @Andrej But can I do the list formatting part automatically?

Comment: @TanukiJoe If you want to pretty format the dictionary to output you can use for example `import json;print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))`

Comment: @AndrejKesely out= {}

for v in parsf2:
    k,v = v.split(maxsplit=1)
    out[k] = [w.strip() for w in v.splitlines()]
print(out)        raises an error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @TanukiJoe That means some data doesn't have the first date part - I suggest to clean the list first (or put there a check). See my edited answer.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Checked the code again. Now everithing works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
a = ['06/07/20\n 22,43€ gas\n 34,70€ street toll', ' 08/07/20\n 74,90€ street toll', ' 13/07/20\n 78€ street toll\n 157,90€ gas']
d = {k.splitlines()[0] : list(map(str.strip, k.splitlines()[1:])) for k in a }
```

#### output

```
{'06/07/20': [' 22,43€ gas', ' 34,70€ street toll'],
 ' 08/07/20': [' 74,90€ street toll'],
 ' 13/07/20': [' 78€ street toll', ' 157,90€ gas']}
```

Comment: Great one-liner! Works like a charm thanks!

Comment: Can you please upvote if you like

Answer (score 0):

```html
final_result = {}
for entry in parsf2:
    entries = entry.split("\n")
    final_result[entries[0]] = entries[1:]

>>> final_result
{'06/07/20': [' 22,43€ gas', ' 34,70€ street toll'], ' 08/07/20': [' 74,90€ street toll'], ' 13/07/20': [' 78€ street toll', ' 157,90€ gas']}
```

Comment: If you change 
    final_result[entries[0]] = entries[1:]
to
    final_result[entries[0].strip()] = [e.strip() for e in entries[1:]]

you can get rid of the spaces / blanks in the beginnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `split` and `dict comprehension`,

```
In [1]: {i.split(maxsplit=1)[0]:i.split(maxsplit=1)[1].split('\n') for i in lst}
Out[1]: 
{'06/07/20': ['22,43€ gas', ' 34,70€ street toll'],
 '08/07/20': ['74,90€ street toll'],
 '13/07/20': ['78€ street toll', ' 157,90€ gas']}
```